# MongoDB TTL index document not deleted on time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ttl

**I am trying to delete a  MongoDB document after 5 minutes but it deleted almost after 2 min. I exactly don't know the issue. Any help is highly appreciated.**

```
  const hospitalRecordSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  hospital_id: {
    type: String,
  },
  hospital_name: {
    type: String,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
    expires: "5m",
    index: true,
  },
  data: {
    type: Object,
    default: {},
  },
});

hospitalRecordSchema.index({ created_at: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 300 });

module.exports = mongoose.model("HospitalRecord", hospitalRecordSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `expireAfterSeconds` `fieldName` set the timer using "expires" because you are using mongoose method `index()` instead of the `createIndex()` method which takes in `expireAfterSeconds` to set the timer and `index()` method takes in a field named "expires" to set the timer ...